# Jaspersoft espacio entre tablas

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper

Herramienta: Jaspersoft studio 6.3.0

Tengo un problema con el espaciado entre tablas, 
tengo varias tablas que toman datos de DataSets
y no logro hacer que haya un espaciado. 
Cada tabla esta con Position Type : Fix relative To Top y Vertical Layout.
Alguna sugerencia de como lograr el espaciado, por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el atributo Position Type a "Float" Y ubica cada tabla una sobre la otra dejando el espacio que quieres que tome.

Float - El objeto se verá afectado según el en relación con los objetos al rededor.

Fix Relative To Top - El objeto se posiciona en relación a la parte superior de la banda.

Comment: por que? recuerda siempre argumentar tu respuesta

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia shadow

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero ya lo solucione, El punto solo era colocar los elementos en este caso las tablas en bandas separadas.. De todas maneras probare tu respuesta.